# Sitecore 8 - Mongo automation DB

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am setting up Sitecore 8 and a few of the blogs mention the “automation.live”, “automation.history” DBs.

[**Example**](http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2014/June/Copy_of_One_Month_with_Sitecore_7-5_Part_3)

But in the [official documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/xdb_configuration_guide_sc75-a4.pdf) there is no mention of these

Does anyone know what “automation.live” & "“automation.history” are for, and if they are required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example blog relates to an early pre-release version of the xDB, and I don't think it's accurate now.

It's likely that the function of those databases has now been picked up by "tracking.live", "tracking.history" and "analytics".

Here is the connection strings file from one of my local Sitecore 8 implementations:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <!-- 
    Sitecore connection strings.
    All database connections for Sitecore are configured here.
  -->
  <add name="core" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sc80rev150121Sitecore_core;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=secret" />
  <add name="master" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sc80rev150121Sitecore_master;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=secret" />
  <add name="web" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sc80rev150121Sitecore_web;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=secret" />
  <add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/sc80rev150121_analytics" />
  <add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/sc80rev150121_tracking_live" />
  <add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/sc80rev150121_tracking_history" />
  <add name="tracking.contact" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/sc80rev150121_tracking_contact" />
  <add name="reporting" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sc80rev150121Sitecore_reporting;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=secret" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I did think that, but just wanted it confirmed, do you have  a version of 8 running without the “automation” DB's? Could you share a  ConnectionStrings.config

Comment: Yep. Amended my answer

Comment: Thanks, interesting the [7.5 documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/xdb_configuration_guide_sc75-a4.pdf) does not mention "tracking.contact", but [8 does](https://doc.sitecore.net/products/sitecore%20experience%20platform/xdb%20configuration/server%20configuration%20features)